# HL7 Parsing with Multiple Messages using python

Tags: python, hl7

I am working on HL7 file parsing.

On daily basis I will get the HL7 file logs, which contain multiple messages inside a single file.

I have chosen the http://python-hl7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html library for parsing,  but this is parsing only one message. If i give a file stream, it will not parse it.

How can we parse multiple messages in a file stream using python.

Comment: I am trying to do exact same thing but couldn't figure out yet. Did find any way to do that by any chance?

Comment: @venkat I want to use this library for my production. How is your experience ?Is it worth using. Please suggest any other python package for HL7 parsing if you know any.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to split the file into individual messages before parsing. If the file contains HL7 message start and end characters, then You can use those as markers. Another way would be to split the file at each MSH segment, because each message should contain a MSH as the first segment.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple messages in one file should be enclosed with the [HL7 Batch File Protocol](http://www.corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-batch-file-protocol). 
You can test this with **hl7.isfile(line)** and you get the messages with **hl7.split_file(hl7file)**.

from the [python hl7 api parse documentation](http://python-hl7.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#hl7.parse)

```
hl7.isfile(line)
   Files are wrapped in FHS / FTS FHS = file header segment FTS = file trailer segment

hl7.split_file(hl7file)
   Given a file, split out the messages. Does not do any validation on the message. Throws away batch and file segments.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution, I split at the MSH segment so that I can parse the msgs separately:

```
with open('file_path/file_name.txt') as msgs:
start = False
for line in msgs.readlines():
    if line[:3] == 'MSH':
        if start:
            parsed_msg = hl7.parse(msg)
            print(parsed_msg)
            start = False
        msg = line
        start = True
    else:
        msg += line
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying. Is this a solution to the question, or a new question about your code? If it's a solution, please edit the answer to make that clear. If it's a question, I recommend asking it as a separate question, maybe linking to this question if it provides relevant context.

Comment: This is a solution @joanis
If there are multiple msgs in a file one after the another without a separator and in a situation that you don't have control over adding the separator at the file creation side.